# I am tring to get an .xslt to output to a .txt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get an .xslt script to output the results to a .txt file. The .xslt file is creating a .xml file. I have been looking at this for a while. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:Message="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
            xmlns:BankPositivePay="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankBositivePay">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
<header>
  <records>
    <xsl:for-each select="//BankPositivePay:BankPositivePay/BankPositivePay:BankAccountTable/BankPositivePay:BankChequeTable">

        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountID" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountNum" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeStatus" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeNum" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AmountCur" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:TransDate" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:RecipientAccountNum" />

        <xsl:text></xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </records>
</header>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the exact text result you would like to get.

Comment: I would like to see the txt file look something like this `000000000011111111110000000000MMDDYYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP` I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, how do you run the transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting the `<header><records>` tags to be doing if you're expecting a non-XML output.

Comment: I am running the base XSL/Transform, but MS Dynamics AX is instantiating the xslt code. I hope that helps. As far as the header and record tags, I apologize. I am new to XSLT/XML.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to see the txt file look something like this
>   000000000011111111110000000000MMDDYYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP I hope this is
>   what you are looking for.

No, I am afraid that's not telling us much. In fact, it's an unintelligible stream of characters.

In the interest of moving this forward, try the following stylesheet as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:BankPositivePay="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankBositivePay">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//BankPositivePay:BankPositivePay/BankPositivePay:BankAccountTable/BankPositivePay:BankChequeTable">
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountID" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountNum" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeStatus" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeNum" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AmountCur" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:TransDate" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:RecipientAccountNum" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output all of the values you have requested in one jumbled text block (just as your example above). If that's not what you want, then insert the appropriate separators by using `xsl:text`, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//BankPositivePay:BankPositivePay/BankPositivePay:BankAccountTable/BankPositivePay:BankChequeTable">
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountID" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AccountNum" />
        <xsl:text>,  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeStatus" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:ChequeNum" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:AmountCur" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:TransDate" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BankPositivePay:RecipientAccountNum" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```